# Будет ли Spring создавать бины классов реализующих интерфейс, если интерфейсу поставить @Component?

Tags: java, spring, аннотации, implementation

Есть интерфейс с кодом

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public interface Reader {
    MeasurementData[] read(Object address);
}
```

Будет ли Spring создавать бины классов реализующих интерфейс?

Может я не сильно внимателен, но в документации я ничего не увидел про использование аннотации при наследовании

Comment: [читай тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502450/interfaces-are-annotated-with-component-annotation-in-spring-ioc-di-what-could)

Comment: @стасевич, огромное спасибо